# Find a display style attribute on list (<li> tag)

Tags: html-lists, display, selectors-api

To simplify:

I've got a list items in my web page created dinamically.

```
<li style="display:none" data-slide="1"> 1 </li>
<li style="display:none" data-slide="2"> 2 </li>
<li data-slide="3"> 3 </li>
<li style="display:none" data-slide="4"> 4 </li>
<li data-slide="5"> 5 </li>
```

and so on (some items appear and others don't).

Just for knowledge:
Obviously this list is inside some  container, but it shouldn't matter to solve my problem.

Now, in a big JS file that manages the full behavior of the site, at one point, I need to change the display style attribute of some items accordingly with my parameters.

So I try this:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-slide]");  // all items have [data-slide]
for ( var m in listItems) {
if (-- my parameters --) listItems[m].style.display = 'block';
else listItems[m].style.display = 'none';
   }
```

The error I obtain (from Firefox console) is: **Uncaught TypeError: listItems[m].style is undefined**

What's wrong? why I can't access or change the display attribute?

I did several tests:

replacing the code with the snippet below:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-slide]");  // all items have [data-slide]
console.log(listItems);
for ( var m in listItems) {
console.log(listItems.style);
   }
```

I obtain this output (from Firefox console) :

```
NodeList(42) [ li, li.active, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, … ]  from the first log

CSS2Properties { display → "none" }
CSS2Properties(0)
CSS2Properties { display → "none" }
CSS2Properties { display → "none" }
CSS2Properties(0)
```

and so on (the items are 42)

I can't understand because the listItems.style seems to exist but if I add listItems.style.display the browser tell me 'is undefined'.

What am I doing wrong?
Where am I wrong to address the display attributes?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

All Right!
I've found the right answer!
I post it below to help someone in the future:

```
for (const lst of listItems.entries()) {  // using for..of and .entries()
if ( -- my parameters --) lst.style.display = 'block';
else lst.style.display = 'none';
 }
```

Comment: The question should be more specific to the problem itself (how to use the display style attribute) and not a long explanation of your personal setup.